# Transformation/projection equation of gps coordinates (lat and long) from pixel coordinates of objects in python

Tags: python, geolocation, map-projections

Good evening guys, a somewhat difficult exercise. Let me explain briefly: I have performed an object recognition with yolov5 from a drone and now I have to perform a transformation/projection of gps coordinates (lat and long) from the pixel coordinates recognised by yolo in order to geolocalise objects. The available data are:
frame number, latitude and longitude of the centre of the frame, height, yaw, pixel position (px and py ) of the recognised object and size (w and h).  My exercise is to transform Lat and Long centre of each frame to the current position of the object based on the pixel position of the detected object.
Among the data I have the fov angle, zoom, hfov, the resolution of each frame.

Here is the starting txt file:

```
Frame Lat Long Alt Yaw Px Py w h
901 37.53697 15.068869 14.932 -175.4 1400 574 39 65
902 37.53697 15.068869 14.932 -175.4 1401 580 42 66
903 37.536969 15.068869 14.929 -175.4 1402 588 41 65
904 37.536969 15.068869 14.929 -175.4 1402 593 40 68
905 37.536969 15.068869 14.929 -175.4 1403 598 38 67
906 37.536968 15.068869 14.928 -175.6 1404 604 39 65
907 37.536968 15.068869 14.928 -175.6 1407 610 40 65
908 37.536968 15.068869 14.928 -175.6 1406 617 40 70
909 37.536967 15.068869 14.927 -175.6 1408 624 41 64
910 37.536967 15.068869 14.927 -175.6 1408 630 39 64
911 37.536967 15.068869 14.927 -175.6 1409 636 38 66
912 37.536967 15.068869 14.928 -175.5 1412 642 40 64
913 37.536967 15.068869 14.928 -175.5 1412 648 40 66
914 37.536967 15.068869 14.928 -175.5 1412 654 41 64
915 37.536966 15.068869 14.929 -175.5 1413 658 38 65
```

Here is the code applied to a specific frame (the 906):

```
#906 frame   14.928 -175.6 1404 604 39 65
# lat/long --> (37.536968, 15.068869)
# pixel --> (1404, 604)  
import math
hfovan=84 *math.pi/180 # fov angle
h=149.28 #h in dm
z=2  #zoom
hfov=2*h*math.tan(hfovan/2)/z
#resol
hres=1920
vres=1080
g_km = 111.139 # km --> g/km
A = hfov/hres/g_km   #transform in grade 
yaw = -175.6*math.pi/180
D = math.sin(yaw)
B = math.cos(yaw)
E = A
C = 37.536968  #lat
F = 15.068869 #lng
px = 1404
py = 604

#formula 
mx = C + A * ((px-hres/2)*B  - (py-vres/2)*D)
my = F - E * ((px-hres/2)*D + (py-vres/2)*B)


print ('Lat:', mx)
print ('Long:',my)
```

The object's true position or ground truth is this:
#GT --> 37.536977   15.068854

but I obtain: 37.261209658577, 15.130520189370717

As a result of precision, I have that when the object is in the middle of the screen it is geolocalised well, while when it is on the side (as in this case) it misses by about 4-5 meters.

Does anyone know if I have applied the formulas correctly or if I need to consider some other parameters?

Thank you in advance for your reply.